# Get DTE for VS2010 addin using VB?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am converting a Visual Studio 2010 macro to work in an addin. I am using VB. How do I correct the line below:

```
Dim win As Window = DTE.ActiveWindow
```

which gives this error:

> Error 3   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object
>   reference.    C:\Users\Frank\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\MyAddin2\MyAddin2\Module1.vb    28

Answer (score 0):

The DTE is passed via the *Application* parameter in [IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.onconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).  This method is called when the AddIn is initialized by Visual Studio.

The AddIn project wizard should have generated some code that casts the *Application* parameter to a field of type *DTE2*.  Use that field to access the *ActiveWindow* property.